# Fast switching between two images?

Tags: java, image

I want to make an object to open mouth and close it using two images that switch quickly. I tried with a for loop but it lagged my game.

```
 if(direction == Constant.UP){

        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src\\images\\pacman up.png");
        image = i.getImage();

        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("src\\images\\pacman left.png");
        image = i2.getImage();

        }
 G.drawImage(image, x, y, 20,20,null);
```

Comment: That's not enough to go by.  *"I tried with a for-loop"* worries me as this should actually block the UI, but it sounds like you're using a thread somewhere...

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) But as a general tip, load the images when the component instance is constructed & store them as class level attributes. 3) If `G` is a graphics instance it should be called `g`.  Further, if it comes from a component it will have an `ImageObserver` - so `g.drawImage(image, x, y, 20,20,this);`.

Answer (score 3):

Any animation in Swing needs to take into consideration the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

You should NEVER perform any action within the content of the EDT that may block it (such as loops or I/O) as this will prevent the EDT from (amongst other things) processing paint requests.

You should always use a surface capable of supporting double buffer, such as `JPanel` as this will help eliminate flickering

The following uses a `javax.swing.Timer` to switch between the two images...

[image][image]

```
public class TestPacMan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPacMan();
    }

    public TestPacMan() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PacManPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PacManPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage pacOpened;
        private BufferedImage pacClosed;
        private BufferedImage frame;
        private boolean opened = true;

        public PacManPane() {
            try {
                pacOpened = ImageIO.read(new File("PC-Closed.png"));
                pacClosed = ImageIO.read(new File("PC-Opened.png"));
                frame = pacOpened;
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    opened = !opened;
                    frame = opened ? pacOpened : pacClosed;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (frame != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(frame, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't create the icon each time. create the two images at startup and just switch back
and forth at runtime.

```
if(direction == Constant.UP){
    image = open;
}else {
    image = closed;
}

G.drawImage(image, x, y, 20,20,null);
```

Comment: If `G` comes from a component it will have an ImageObserver - so `G.drawImage(image, x, y, 20,20,this);`.

Comment: or even better: `g.drawImage(direction == Constant.UP ? open : closed, x, y, 20, 20, null);`

Comment: terniary expressions leave me cold. I prefer if else.